# How to validate SSL ciphers list?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I found many useful online tools that provide SSL/TLS analysis. Is there any offline or online tool that would check if specific ciphers are safe?

Sometimes servers are not visible in internet or admin wish not to inform the rest of the world that his server is not safe enough.

I know that I can run nmap against my own server, however quick static analysis would be fine.

Comment: *"... quick static analysis would be fine"* - A static analysis would require a tool specific for this (unknown) server type which has access to the relevant part of the servers configuration. Depending on the server it might also need to know which OpenSSL version is linked to the server and which compile options this OpenSSL version has. Thus, one can probably create such a tool for a specific case but there is no general tool which can be applied to do a static analysis against all types of server.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, now I'm a bit more aware of fact that many variables need to be taken into account during that check.

Answer (score 0):

For example, Qualys sells this product that you need for internal scanning. If you're not going to buy anything, you can script around openssl (it wouldn't take long).